# Decomposition of forcing iterations

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

One of the great things about a finite support iteration $\Bbb P_\delta$, is that if $\alpha<\delta$, we can write $\Bbb P_\delta$ as the iteration of $\Bbb{P_\alpha\ast\dot Q_\alpha\ast P_\delta/P_{\alpha+1}}$. Indeed, even just the fact that $\Bbb{P_\delta=P_\alpha\ast P_\delta/P_\alpha}$ is by itself the great thing about finite support iterations.

Generally, if we want to decompose non-finite support iterations, then we need them to be somehow "revised", in the sense that the support can change based on the "new cofinality of the ordinal" below certain conditions.

**Question.** Is there some reasonable condition which lets us decompose countable support, or generally $\kappa$-support or even Easton-support iterations?

More specifically, does closure of the iterands (matching with the support of the iteration in the obvious way, e.g. $\kappa$-closed iterands for $\kappa$-support iterations) suffice? If not, what would be a fun counterexample?

Comment: In a countable-support iteration, it suffices that the initial part of the forcing is proper for the tail to be (equivalent to) a genuine countable-support iteration. Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Well, yes and no. I was hoping for something that generalizes a bit better in arbitrary cases than properness. It might be that $\kappa^+$-closure works just fine (which would work in the case of properness and $\sigma$-closure, according to your comment). But I actually want more, not just "a genuine countable-support iteration", but really the tail of the iterands.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the iterands in the tail are the same. You should probably be able to generalize from proper to "every new countable set is covered by an old countable set", and analogously for larger supports.

Comment: And therein lies the rub, what happens when you want to consider mixed support iterations, e.g. Easton support iterations?

Comment: Sure. I suppose that in the typical case you're going to be splitting an Easton iteration at stage kappa and $\mathbb{P}_\kappa$ will be $\kappa^+$-cc, so it should still be fine. But you're not interested in the typical case...

Comment: Asaf, have you looked at Lemma 21.8. in Jech? It seems to me that this is what you want.

Comment: @Stefan: That seems to be along the lines I'm thinking about. But I need to read this more closely, since Jech is using the somewhat ambiguous terms "direct" and "inverse" limits, and mentions after the lemma itself that it is "not formulated correctly" (something about mismatch of "what kind of names are we using", which seems to be inconsequential in the overall scheme of things). Thanks.

Comment: You can always decompose an iteration as described above. The question is just what kinds of properties the quotient has.

Comment: @Monroe: Yes, that's the point. I want the quotient to be itself an iteration (or a name for an iteration) which is "of the same type", more or less.